# AWS Import Cognito Users with a Temp Password

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I have been tasked with importing users from an old MYSQL database into AWS Cognito as we are currently building another platform and planning on using SSO across them all.

Obviously, in the MYSQL database the user has passwords, but what I want to achieve is that after the import has been completed, the user would attempt to sign in and be prompted to create a new password (with no time limit).

I can see that the PHP SDK contains a `AdminSetUserPassword` method where I can set `Permanent` to false, which looks like it puts the status of that user to `FORCE_CHANGE_PASSWORD.

On the face of it, this looks great, however, the documentation (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_AdminSetUserPassword.html) contains a worrying choice of wording:

```
If the user does not sign in before it expires, the user will not be able to sign in and their password will need to be reset by an administrator.
```

What does this mean? Does this mean that if the user signs in for the first time, a countdown starts, and if they do not complete the new password flow (which I will need to setup in the various clients) then the support desk is going to be inundated with calls with users unable to login to their account?

Or, does `and their password will need to be reset by an administrator` mean that I can still user the Admin functionality in the SDK to change the users password after the expiry?

Another issue is, that during import, I am required to sign the user in in order to communicate with the other API's, this will then trigger that sign timer.

Am I missing any other way of handling this? Essentially, I need to make the whole process as seamless as possible for the users and minimal updates to each of the clients (some are really old codebases, but as they communicate to a older central API I have managed to handle the Cognito auth process via that so haven't had to update the clients yet).

Comment: How are you creating the users?

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary Using `adminCreateUser` in the PHP SDK (importer)

Comment: Does the existing  database actually contain passwords, or hashes?

Comment: I think you want this: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_AdminResetUserPassword.html

Comment: @ChrisHaas Hashes

How would this flow look like when attempting to import the users using my import script. 

The import script needs to authenticate the user (so I can use the token to access other API's).

Would I set a perm password, then hit that endpoint so when the user logs in to the clients it would through the PasswordResetRequired Exception?

Comment: It sounds like you do have user passwords then. When I've built these migrations in the past, the requirements were always to "migrate all the users", however, because we never store passwords, the migration took place over time. When a user signs into your application, it looks to see if they are in the new auth system and if not, that's when the user migration happens. The user authenticates, _they_ get a token, and the remaining steps for the migration are taken in their context (or through a background queue) with a "please wait while we upgrade your account" message.

Comment: @ChrisHaas

We are already kind of doing this, this is step 1 and will be launched shortly. The old app has been replaced to use Cognito, so when the user logs in (we then have their password to create the Cognito account for them). This will capture active users at the first instance. 

The issue is the older, less active users, I think the client also wants to close down the older DB's etc. ASAP for costs (it's not optimised at all and very fragmented, it must be costing them a small fortune), so the idea was to just run a single migration over a weekend.

Comment: Yeah, I understand that, but, I would still phase this. You don't need to keep the old app alive, just the information related to the user. If your model is simple, you could literally store this data in a protected CSV file as legacy, although ideally it would be a database. It really depends on the complexity of your user model, if it is just username and password, or if there's a lot of extra stuff.